# $a,b,c$ real, summing to two and multiplying to four; find minimum of $|a|+|b|+|c|$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Knowing that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers with
>   $$a+b+c=2\qquad abc=4$$
>   find the smallest value of $|a|+|b|+|c|$.

The answer's supposed to be 6 but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? A couple immediate thoughts:  the symmetry lets you assume $a \le b \le c$.  What are the choices for how many are positive?  There are two.  Can you eliminate one?  You have two equations in three unknowns, so should be able to choose one "as you wish".  Plug that into your objective, take a derivative, set to zero....

Comment: Weel, at first I tried to multiply $a+b+c=2$ by $a,b,c$ or a combination of the three in order to make the product abcabc appear and then use $abc=4$, then I try to use some notable products, then I tried to use $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$, thinking that I would have to use $|a|^2=a^2$ somehow, but got stuck with the 2(ab+bc+ac), with no clue to what to do

Comment: I spend a couple of hours on that. Then I try to search online for the question, no luck. Then I try to search for the question in English (because my mother language is Portuguese), soo I had to translate, the best I could, the question. Then I end up here. That's what I tried.

Comment: Never thought that I would have to use $a≤b≤c$. I didn't understand the "the symmetry lets you assume(...)", how? I accept book suggestions or even wikipedia. Sure, I thought that or $0≤a≤b≤c$ or two of then are negative numbers but that didn't help much more. Yes, I was hoping to get a easy substitution, couldn't see any. You gave me more questions then answers and suggest to use derivative out of nowhere. Sorry, but what you said wasn't helpful for me

Comment: Because everything in the problem is symmetric in $a,b,c$ any solution allows you to permute the values any way you want.  That is what allows you to assume $a \le b \le c$-every solution can be put in that form.  The reason I suggested a derivative was taking "smaller" as "smallest" and expecting that there would be a range of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

If $c>0$ then by AM-GM $$2=a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3\sqrt[3]4,$$
which is contradiction.

Thus, $c<0$ and since $abc>0$ we obtain $b<0$.

Now, we can write our problem in the following words.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=4$ and $a-b-c=2$.
>
> Find the minimal value of $a+b+c$.

Indeed, the condition gives: $bc=\frac{4}{a}$ and $b+c=a-2$, which says that
$$(a-2)^2\geq\frac{16}{a}$$ or
$$(a-4)(a^2+4)\geq0.$$
Thus, $b+c=a-2\geq2$ and $a+b+c\geq4+2=6$.

The equality occurs in the last case for $a=4$ and $b=c=1$, which is

$a=4$ and $b=c=-1$ for the original problem.

Done!

Comment: Ok, english isn't my mother language/tongue, but I could make sense of what you wrote and understand most of it. Just a few questions:$$$$1- AM-GM stands for "Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality"? $$$$ 2- How exactly did you get to the $(a-2)^2\geq\frac{16}{a}$?$$$$ 3 - How did you get that $b+c=a-2\geq2$, I mean, how did you figure it out that it has to be greater or equal to two?

Comment: And thank you very much. I didn't know that the problem has about inequality. You make the question look very easy and effortless. Do you have any book or text recommendation/suggestion?

Comment: @2plus2 1. Yes. 2. Because $(b+c)^2\geq4bc$ 3. I got before that $a\geq4$. Thus, $b+c-2=a-2\geq4-2=2$. 4.  I think the best "book" it's   hour by hour, day by day,  always to prove inequalities and  to see, how other persons do it.